# How to get Wikipedia page id from Wikidata id?

Tags: python, wikipedia, wikidata, wikidata-query-service

I want to get the Wikipedia page id from the Wikidata id, how can I get it from the Wikidata Query Service or other methods with python? Because I do not see any attribute in wikidata called something like wikipedia id.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure, if DBpedia always contains both wikiPageID and Wikidata ID, but you can try the folowing query on DBpedia:

```sql
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/> 
SELECT ?wikipedia_id WHERE {
    ?dbpedia_id owl:sameAs ?wikidata_id  .
    ?dbpedia_id dbo:wikiPageID ?wikipedia_id .
    VALUES (?wikidata_id) {(wd:Q123)} 
}
```

[Try it!](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?qtxt=PREFIX+wd%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E+%0D%0ASELECT+%3Fwikipedia_id+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A++++%3Fdbpedia_id+owl%3AsameAs+%3Fwikidata_id++.%0D%0A++++%3Fdbpedia_id+dbo%3AwikiPageID+%3Fwikipedia_id+.%0D%0A++++VALUES+(%3Fwikidata_id)+%7B(wd%3AQ123)%7D+%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml)

Or you can try the following federated query on Wikidata:

```sql
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/> 
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> 
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>  

SELECT ?wikipedia_id where {
    VALUES (?wikidata_id)  {(wd:Q123)}
    SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> {
       ?dbpedia_id owl:sameAs ?wikidata_id .
       ?dbpedia_id dbo:wikiPageID ?wikipedia_id 
    } 
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#PREFIX%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20owl%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23%3E%0APREFIX%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20%3Fwikipedia_id%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fwikidata_id%29%20%20%7B%28wd%3AQ123%29%7D%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fsparql%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fdbpedia_id%20owl%3AsameAs%20%3Fwikidata_id%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fdbpedia_id%20dbo%3AwikiPageID%20%3Fwikipedia_id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

**Update**

You can call out to the Wikipedia API using [MWAPI](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual/MWAPI) on Wikidata:

```sql
SELECT ?pageid WHERE {
    VALUES (?item) {(wd:Q123)} 
    [ schema:about ?item ; schema:name ?name ;
      schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/> ]
     SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
         bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "en.wikipedia.org" .
         bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "Generator" .
         bd:serviceParam mwapi:generator "allpages" .
         bd:serviceParam mwapi:gapfrom ?name .
         bd:serviceParam mwapi:gapto ?name .
         ?pageid wikibase:apiOutput "@pageid" .
    }
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fpageid%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fitem%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ123%29%7D%20%0A%20%20%20%20%5B%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fitem%20%3B%20schema%3Aname%20%3Fname%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%3E%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Amwapi%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Aendpoint%20%22en.wikipedia.org%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Aapi%20%22Generator%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20mwapi%3Agenerator%20%22allpages%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20mwapi%3Agapfrom%20%3Fname%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20mwapi%3Agapto%20%3Fname%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fpageid%20wikibase%3AapiOutput%20%22%40pageid%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Unfortunately, it seems you [have to use](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual/MWAPI#Supported_services) a generator; `allpages` appears to be the most suitable one.

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to get the Wikipedia page `title` from the Wikidata id, which can be done with a request to Wikidata API [`wbgetentities`](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbgetentities) module, like so: [`https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q123&format=json&props=sitelinks`](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q123&format=json&props=sitelinks)

Then, once you found the Wikipedia title from the desired Wikipedia edition, you can get the associated page id from that Wikipedia API: [`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=September&format=json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=September&format=json)

So from those example URLs you can get that:
Wikidata id = `Q123`
=> English Wikipedia (`enwiki`) title = `September`
=> pageid = `15580374`

Answer (score 1):

Use below URL in your CURL call. You have to change WikiDataID Q243 in below link.

For Example if you want wikiPageID of **Taj_Mahal** then **replace Q243 with Q9141** in below link and do CURL call.

> http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX+wd%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E+%0D%0ASELECT+%3FwikiPageID+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A%3Fdbpedia_id+owl%3AsameAs+%3Fwikidata_id++.%0D%0A%3Fdbpedia_id+dbo%3AwikiPageID+%3FwikiPageID+.%0D%0AVALUES+%28%3Fwikidata_id%29+%7B%28wd%3AQ243%29%7D+%0D%0A%7D&format=application%2Fsparql-results%2Bjson&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=+Run+Query

To Get WikiPageID through wikiDataId you have to modify above link or by replacing wikiDataID of your choice in above link.

**Note:**

1) To Get WikiPageID with Label use [this URL](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%20%0D%0ASELECT%20%3FwikiPageID%20%3Flabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%3Fdbpedia_id%20owl%3AsameAs%20%3Fwikidata_id%20%20.%0D%0A%3Fdbpedia_id%20dbo%3AwikiPageID%20%3FwikiPageID%20.%0D%0A%3Fdbpedia_id%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%20%3Flabel%20.%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3Flabel%20%29%20%3D%20%27en%27%29%20.%0D%0AVALUES%20%28%3Fwikidata_id%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ243%29%7D%20%0D%0A%7D&format=application%2Fsparql-results%2Bjson&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query) in CURL Call

2) Find Q243 and Replace with your wikiDataID