# Get Wikipedia page ID from WikiData ID

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, wikidata, wikidata-query-service

I want to get Wikipedia page ID from Wikidata ID from Wikidata Query Service in a single SPARQL query.

First SPARQL query to get Wikidata ID (`wd:Q3131`) from title page: "Alpes-de-Haute-Provence"

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription WHERE {
            ?url rdf:type schema:Article;
            schema:about ?item; schema:name ?name ;
            schema:isPartOf <https://fr.wikipedia.org/>;
            schema:name "Alpes-de-Haute-Provence"@fr.
          SERVICE wikibase:label {
            bd:serviceParam
            wikibase:language "fr,[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en"
          }
}
```

Second SPARQL query to get Wikipedia page ID from Wikidata ID

```
SELECT ?pageid WHERE {
    VALUES (?item) {(wd:Q3131)} 
    [ schema:about ?item ; schema:name ?name ;
      schema:isPartOf <https://fr.wikipedia.org/> ]
     SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
         bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "fr.wikipedia.org" .
         bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "Generator" .
         bd:serviceParam mwapi:generator "allpages" .
         bd:serviceParam mwapi:gapfrom ?name .
         bd:serviceParam mwapi:gapto ?name .
         ?pageid wikibase:apiOutput "@pageid" .
    }
}
```

Is possible to do it in a single SPARQL query?

Comment: why should it not? I mean, all the second query does is to get additional information. Here is the query:

Comment: `SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription ?pageid WHERE {
            ?url rdf:type schema:Article;
            schema:about ?item; schema:name ?name ;
            schema:isPartOf <https://fr.wikipedia.org/>;
            schema:name "Alpes-de-Haute-Provence"@fr.
          SERVICE wikibase:label {
            bd:serviceParam
            wikibase:language "fr,[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en"
          }`

Comment: `SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
         bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "fr.wikipedia.org" .
         bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "Generator" .
         bd:serviceParam mwapi:generator "allpages" .
         bd:serviceParam mwapi:gapfrom ?name .
         bd:serviceParam mwapi:gapto ?name .
         ?pageid wikibase:apiOutput "@pageid" .
    }
}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Wikipedia page id from Wikidata id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43746798/how-to-get-wikipedia-page-id-from-wikidata-id)

Comment: Almost in principle. @Uninformed answers my question exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution proposed by [@UninformedUser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4744359/uninformeduser)

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription ?pageid WHERE {             
  ?url rdf:type schema:Article;             
  schema:about ?item; 
  schema:name ?name ;             
  schema:isPartOf <https://fr.wikipedia.org/>;             
  schema:name "Alpes-de-Haute-Provence"@fr.           
  SERVICE wikibase:label {             
    bd:serviceParam             
    wikibase:language "fr,[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en"           
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "fr.wikipedia.org" .          
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "Generator" .          
    bd:serviceParam mwapi:generator "allpages" .          
    bd:serviceParam mwapi:gapfrom ?name .          
    bd:serviceParam mwapi:gapto ?name .          
    ?pageid wikibase:apiOutput "@pageid" .     
  } 
}
```